# Calling contact WITHOUT any permissions

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions

I'm using following function to call a number:

```
private static void startCall(Context context, String phoneNumber)
{
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
    context.startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

Android studio recently tells me this may fail because of missing permissions. I thought, this way would be possible on any device without permissions...

So how would I make the above solution work on android 6 as well? I just want the app to open an installed phone app, I don't want my app to directly call somebody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought, this way would be possible on any device without permissions

No.

> I just want the app to open an installed phone app, I don't want my app to directly call somebody

Then `ACTION_CALL` was the wrong solution in the first place. `ACTION_DIAL` can be used without permissions, and it launches the device dialer app, with your supplied phone number filled in.

Comment: Thanks. And for sms I have to use ACTION_SEND with ` callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber));` to avoid the warning and any problems, correct?

Comment: @prom85: I'm not sure what "the warning" is. `ACTION_SEND` doesn't use the `Uri`. For SMS, you probably want `ACTION_SENDTO` with an `smsto:` `Uri`.

Comment: The warning was about the missing permissions and the `SecurityException` that may be raised because of that. Thanks